For what value of $k$ will $kx^2+x+k=0$ have two real solutions?
The answer key says $-1/2 < k < 1/2$, yet when I tried $k=0$ in the equation, I received only one solution of $x=0$. However, the discriminant with $k =0$, is still greater than $0$. What is going on here, and how does one find such cases? Thanks!

The answer should be $-1/2<k<0$ or $0<k<1/2$. If $k=0$, $kx^2+x+k$ is a polynomial of first degree, hence has only one root.

The quadratic formula divides by the coefficient of the $x^2$ term, so if that is 0 we cannot use the quadratic formula. So the answer key has a small mistake that you did notice. It should be $-1/2 < k< 0$ or $0<k<1/2$.
Another way to think about it is that when $k=0$ we are left with just a linear term which means we cannot have 2 solutions.

Since the quadratic coefficients contain the parameter $k$, we should discuss this in two cases: one where $k = 0$ and the other where $k \not = 0$.
Let's first discuss the case of $k = 0$, when the equation degenerates to $x = 0$. At this point, the equation has only one solution, which is clearly not the case.
Then is the case of $k \not = 0$, then you can list the discriminant of the quadratic equation $\Delta = 1 - 4 k^2$, from the meaning of the question know $\Delta = 1 - 4 k^2 > 0$,Solve $-1/2 < k < 1/2$. So the final result is $k \in (-1/2,0) \cup (0,1/2)$

Suppose that $k\neq 0$:
\begin{align*}
kx^{2} + x + k = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow \left(x^{2} + \frac{x}{k}\right) + 1 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x^{2} + \frac{x}{k} + \frac{1}{4k^{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{4k^{2}} - 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x + \frac{1}{2k}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{4k^{2}} - 1
\end{align*}
Then the LHS is always nonnegative.
To ensure the proposed equation has two distinct roots, the RHS must be positive:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4k^{2}} - 1 > 0 & \Longleftrightarrow 4k^{2} < 1 \Longleftrightarrow |k| < \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
If $k = 0$, then the proposed equation has clearly just one root.
Hopefully this helps!
